# what does the following notation mean?

Tags: c++

I came across this piece of code and I don't understand it:

```
catch (MyException & /* q */) {
```

What do the `/*` and `*/` do? They look like a comment to me but that can't be right. Doesn't a variable need to be specified?

Comment: So you are actually telling you can understand what an exception is, as well as a try/catch statement, and can't understand what a comment is?

Comment: This is a question that got 2 up votes? Really? Where are you people learning how to program from nowadays?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I respect your downvote. After understanding this, I agree it looks like a silly question. But just remember that looking backwards is always easy.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I do not respect your (if it was you) downvote on dasblinkenlight's answer. My question could be bad; but I do not see any problem with his answer.

Comment: @XuWang: Don't take me wrong, but the first thing to know in a language is what is code and what is not. I am truly surprised by the upvotes (more than the question itself), as it indicates that there is people that feel this is an interesting question --maybe it clears some doubt? My question still stands: where is people learning programming from?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I agree that that's important. My thought process was the following: 1. that's a comment 2. but then a variable is not specified. 3. that must not be correct so my assumption in (1) must have been wrong. I'm learning from books by the way but never came across this. This is the kind of situation that I think shows up in practice but not in books.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> They look like a comment to me but that can't be right.

Yes, these *are* [C-style comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1dbk8bw.aspx). They are used to exclude the name of an unused variable, most likely to avoid a warning from the compiler. You can read about them in a C or C++ book of your choice.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thanks! so if the comment were excluded the compiler would complain? So this is a way of keeping the compiler happy but at the same time you don't want to use an actual variable for performance reasons (well this would be optimized out probably, right?) and because it's easier to read? Did I get that right?

Comment: No performance issue... It just avoid a warning, if you configured your compiler to report unused variables. Same is usually done with: ( void )varName;

Comment: @XuWang Sometimes you want to catch the exception, but you do not need to examine the content of its members, so the name of the variable is not used in the exception block. The variable is then optimized out, and a warning is issued. You can remove the comment and the variable name, and you'd get no warning. The reasons to keep the variable in the comments are purely aesthetic.

Comment: @Macmade But without any optimization, if I didn't comment out the variable `q` wouldn't memory be allocated for the symbol "q"? I realize it's just a reference here, but I'm wondering if it weren't a reference and without optimization if memory would be allocated large enough to hold a MyException object and it would be constructed?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ah that's good to know. I'm learning that aesthetics can be important for good programming. I'll keep this in mind. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Macmade ok I'll think about this some more. Thanks.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: The word '*optimization*' should never be used in this discussion, it makes no sense (there is nothing that can be *optimized out*) and brings confusion into the argument.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas "optimized out" idiomatic expression is a synonym for "removed", it has nothing to do with "optimization". You did not downvote an answer based on the content of a **comment**, did you?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I don't find optimized out to be an idiomatic expression synonym of 'removed', and neither seems to be the case of Xu Wang judging from his comment: But without optimization.... It is important to be precise, and even more important to not be misleading.  Note that the compiler will **not** remove the variable --it cannot. It is just left unnamed inside the catch block. Nothing is *optimized*/removed from the code.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas You not *finding* something does not change the harsh reality: "optimized out" universally means "removed by the optimizer", there are no questions or doubts about that. You do not need to take my word for it - feel free to ask around.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Yes, that is my understanding of *optimized out*, and I very much doubt that the argument to the `catch` can be optimized out --> this was the reason of the first comment. I understood from your answer that you meant removed by the program, not the optimizer -- which would be a rather confusing interpretation of *optimized out*. As to my first comment: arguments to functions cannot be *optimized out*. The same goes for caught exceptions when the exception is caught by reference.

Comment: ... I believe that even catch-by-value will not have the argument *optimized out*, but I have not been able to confirm this with documentation. Still, because in the example the argument is caught by reference, there is **nothing** that can be optimized: The exception pointer will still be passed in to the personality routine from the unwind library as determined by the ABI, and whether the landing pad assigns a *name* to the object at the other end of the pointer or not makes no difference regarding the generated code. [*]

Comment: ... [\*] The implementation of the personality routine is defined by the implementation (compiler), so hypothetically, in the case of an exception caught by value it could *optimize* away the copy, but that is unrelated to the *exception-declaration* having a name, as this is explicitly allowed in §12.8/31 as one of the cases where copies can be elided --in that clause it requires the meaning of the program to be unchanged by anything other than the execution of constructors/destructors, which is the case if the *exception* is not *used* regardless of the existence of a name

Comment: ... Summing up: if by *optimized out* you mean that the optimizer will care about the argument to the `catch` having a name, you are just adding noise as the name does not affect. The existence or the name does not affect the generated code at all.

Answer (score 2):

/* */ is for inline comments and multi-line comments.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the exception is commented out to avoid an unused variable warning.

Answer (score 1):

`/* */` are used for inline comments.